# Calling getter for dispatch_queue_t property causes crash

Tags: objective-c, ios9, grand-central-dispatch

I have a private serial queue declared as a property and I am running into a very strange situation.

If I dispatch_async the property, it will crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS  (code=EXC_i386_GPFLT)). After some debugging, I found out that it's because the getter is called. If getter is not called, the crash won't happen. Also, it always crashes the second time self.queue is called. See second example below.

It's as though the first synthesized getter call has somehow caused the ivar to be over-released.

This is targeting iOS 9 and above so I am not checking OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC.

Example 1) This doesn't work:

```
@interface Test ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t initQueue;
@end

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _initQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.initQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)onCompletion:(void (^)())completion {
  // Crashes here - EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_i386_GPFLT) 
  // the second time self.queue is accessed - either by subsequent call into 
  // this method, or by adding NSLog(@"%@", self.queue) before this line.
  dispatch_async(self.initQueue, ^{
    ...
  });
}
```

Example 2) This also doesn't work:

```
@interface Test ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t initQueue;
@end

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _initQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.initQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)onCompletion:(void (^)())completion {
  NSLog(@"%@", self.initQueue);
  // Crashes below - EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) 
  NSLog(@"%@", self.initQueue);
}
```

Example 3) It works if I stay away from using the getter:

```
@interface Test ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t initQueue;
@end

- (instancetype)init {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            _initQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.initQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        }
        return self;
    }

- (void)onCompletion:(void (^)())completion {
  // Works fine
  dispatch_async(_initQueue, ^{
    ...
  });
}
```

Example 4) It also works if I supply the getter:

```
@interface Test ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t initQueue;
@end

- (instancetype)init {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            _initQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.initQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        }
        return self;
    }

- (dispatch_queue_t)initQueue {
  return _initQueue;
}

- (void)onCompletion:(void (^)())completion {
  // Works fine
  dispatch_async(self.initQueue, ^{
    ...
  });
}
```

Example 5) It will also work if I use ivar for queue instead of property or self.initQueue is assigned the main queue instead.

What's the reason for this behavior?

Other open source library is using property for dispatch_queue_t along with the getter and they have no issue at all. Example: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/7e0964f8d90dcd80d535c52dd9f6d5fa7432052b/SDWebImage/SDImageCache.m#L57

Comment: Can you supply the link of the library using it as you said, and why are you not able to supply the getter?

Comment: The example code is my own code.  I am saying I saw other libraries using similar code but they don't have the crash issue that I am experiencing with mine.

Comment: This is an example of existing code that works fine: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/7e0964f8d90dcd80d535c52dd9f6d5fa7432052b/SDWebImage/SDImageCache.m#L57

Comment: I'm suspicious about the life cycle of `Test`. Are you sure it's not getting deallocated before `onCompletion` is called? I'd suggest adding a `dealloc` method and confirm when `Test` is deallocated.

Comment: @Rob Test is a singleton. I confirmed that dealloc is not called - 100% certain. Keep in mind if I stay away from using self.queue directly or supply my own getter, things work fine, as shown in my examples.

Comment: Maybe try something like this... https://gist.github.com/anonymous/71bca0e53cc291dd16250e6486411bed

Comment: @Rob There is no issue with lifecycle, because Example (3) and (4) work fine.  This is a singleton so it stays throughout the lifecycle of the app. I don't think more code will help, something else weird is going on because it seems to work fine in other open source code I saw. Does Example 2 give you any clue? Keep in mind if it is lifecycle issue there is no way onCompletion can be called by the caller without crashing.

Comment: @l'L'l Don't think it has anything to do with onCompletion. Please see Example 3 and 4, which work.

Comment: @Rob I wish I could provide a reproducible example - that would help me nail down the problem too.

Comment: @Rob I found out the issue - it was because the property was called initQueue. The code above will all work fine because I have renamed the example to use queue instead.  Seems like a namespace collision issue.

Comment: @Boon I suspect it has to do with [method families](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#method-families), anything prefixed with `new` or `init` is assumed to be `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` so the return value does not have its retain value incremented, so your retain count was off. You could probably use `_initQueue` if it was a non-property iVar.

Comment: I'd suggest that the problem is not namespace collision, but rather ARC's making inferences of what it should be doing on the basis of the method name. I've seen similar problems with properties whose name begins with `new`.

Comment: For the sake of future readers trying to understand the comments above, when the question was first posed, the name of the property was `queue`, not `initQueue`, but that name is the root of the problem. Properties whose names begin with `init`, `new`, `copy` or `mutableCopy` will suffer problems similar to those shown above.

Comment: @Rob Why would the above work if self.initQueue was assigned dispatch_get_main_queue() instead? It seems like name is not the only element here.

Comment: I glanced at libDispatch source and don't see anything immediately obvious, but bottom line, I wouldn't be surprised if the attempted release/deallocation of the main queue was a noop or something along those lines. For example, if I write manual release code that incorrectly, but deliberately, overreleases a queue I create, it crashes as expected, but if I attempt to overrelease the main queue (or a global queue), there is no crash. Bottom line, I'd hesitate to draw too many conclusions about the failure to crash if doing this with the main or a global queue.

Comment: One final observation: While the best solution is to just rename `initQueue`, as a matter of academic interest, the other solution is to keep that property name, but specify a different getter name, e.g. `@property (strong, nonatomic, getter=foo) dispatch_queue_t initQueue` and then you can refer to `self.foo` to refer to this getter and avoid get ARC problem

Comment: @Rob Good note and it corroborates Example (4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per your comments you originally named the property `initQueue`, this in turn created a method called `initQueue` which fell afoul of [the ARC Method family](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#method-families) rules. Those rules indicate that ARC will automatically annotate any method beginning with `new` or `init` as `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED`.

> Methods in the `init` family implicitly consume their `self` parameter and return a retained object. Neither of these properties can be altered through attributes.

This in turn means that callers of the method are supposed to be safe to assume that they are taking ownership of the returned value and do not need to increment the retain value. As a result when you attempted to use the property ARC did not increase the reference count as was expected but ARC still left a release call at the end of the method. This resulted in your property value being released prior to when your class was `dealloc`ed.

It is possible to override this behavior using attributes in some cases. However I would suggest just being aware of method families, as they can have a nice performance impact on your application particularly for factory methods.

Other pitfalls to be aware of:

> Methods in the `alloc`, `copy`, `mutableCopy`, and `new` families — that is, methods in all the currently-defined families except `init` — implicitly return a retained object as if they were annotated with the `ns_returns_retained` attribute. This can be overridden by annotating the method with either of the `ns_returns_autoreleased` or `ns_returns_not_retained` attributes.

A side note on this as well:

> It is undefined behavior for a program to cause two or more calls to `init` methods on the same object, except that each `init` method invocation may perform at most one delegate `init` call.

Sadly the compiler doesn't seem to warn about that one.

Comment: Curious, why would this work if self.initQueue was assigned dispatch_get_main_queue instead? Maybe the naming is not the only issue here.

Comment: @Boon if I was to guess it's because the main queue cannot be released, and may even have an explicit implementation of `release` to prevent it

Comment: @Boon - BTW, if you don't believe that this name is the root of the problem, I'd suggest you look at the assembler code and you can see evidence that the memory handling generated for different variables is different. It's admittedly a little hard to follow, but you can clearly see that the code ARC generated is different.

Comment: @Rob I totally believe it because issue caused by using init- with the synthesized getter/setter makes total sense. Was curious about the case with dispatch_get_main_queue().  Your explanation and Mgetz's make sense. Wish I could grant selected answer to you both.